# Changing text in qlineedit of qt application in real time

Tags: c++, qt

I want to create a qt application in which a function is called every 10 seconds to change the text in a qlineedit. I'm a newbie to qt programming. Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html) and connect it to a slot that does the update.

This class will do it (note, I typed this directly into StackOverflow, so there are probably compilation errors):

```
class TextUpdater : public QObject {
    public:
        TextUpdater(QLineEdit* lineEdit);
    public slots:
        void updateText();
};


TextUpdater::TextUpdater(QLineEdit* edit)
:QObject(lineEdit), lineEdit(edit)
 // make the line edit the parent so we'll get destroyed
 // when the line edit is destroyed
{
    QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setSingleShot(false);
    timer->setInterval(10 * 1000); // 10 seconds
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateText()));
}

void TextUpdater::updateText()
{
    // Set the text to whatever you want. This is just to show it updating
    lineEdit->setText(QTime::currentTime().toString());
}
```

You will need to modify it to do whatever you need.

Comment: This is pretty slick. I like how you attach it to the lineEdit to delete it on destruction. I'd only add that the `TextUpdater` objects should be created on the heap (i.e., using `new`) if you need it to persist out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [QTimer](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtimer.html) class. //or tell us more about what exactly you don't know how to do it.